# Presenting a navigation crontroller from TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I created a custom button which I centred on my TabBar Controller. I want to use it to present a View Controller attached to a Navigation Controller Modally. But, I keep getting error and the error says I can't push. Whereas, I'm not pushing. I'm presenting

```
 func showView() {
    print("We are here ohhh")
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard")

    //Creating a navigation controller with viewController at the root of the navigation stack.
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!)
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

`The Error`

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

Comment: Would the storyboard view controller "Dashboard" happen to be a `UINavigationController` as well? In that case, you do not need to instantiate a new `UINavigationController`, and instead you can just present `viewController`

Comment: Note that you should likely be using `self.presentViewController` (the version you commented out)

Comment: Thank You very much. Works fine. What if I want to dismiss the Modal View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the storyboard view controller with identifier `"Dashboard"` is a `UINavigationController`, you can just present it directly:

```
func showView() {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard")
    presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

To dismiss (from presenting view controller):

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

To dismiss (from view controller being presented):

```
self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to do this instead:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!)
navController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: true)
self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This fixes the problem with `presentViewController`, but I'm fairly sure that using `setViewControllers` will not make a difference, and therefore this will not fix the OP's problem.